# Meteor Security Permissions on Uploaded Images

Tags: node.js, security, meteor, file-upload

I'm creating a Meteor chat app. I want users to be able to send images to each other, but users not in the group/conversation shouldn't be able to see the image. My first thought was to give an image a unique ID and store the image with this ID in a public folder in my or a 3rd party server.

For example, if the user uploads an image called "name.jpg", it could be stored in Amazon S3 as A3eedAcRCqCa32451.jpg. That way, anyone with the ID can access the image, but the only people with access to the ID would be those in the group chat, since I can ensure secure access using Meteor's publish and subscribe rules. However, this doesn't feel safe to me. Is my intuition right?

If yes, how else would I do it? I searched online and on StackOverflow and couldn't find another simple way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the security level you want...
A more secure solution would be to store in a collection the `imageId` and `userId` of people that can access the image. When someone wants to access it, you just have to check if he's in the list of allowed users.

Then as you said you can use a 3rd party storage (personally I'm using [ostrio:files](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) with Dropbox integration, [the docs](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/DropBox-Integration) about it aren't up to date but I made a pull request which was accepted on the dev branch with a working example, you can take a look at it [here](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/blob/dev/docs/dropbox-integration.md).)

The nice thing with `ostrio:files` is that it offers built-in functions like `onAfterUpload` or `interceptDownload` in which you can store data about access for the first and check if access is allowed for the second.

Comment: Does `interceptDownload` prevent people from accessing the images directly from the image link?

Comment: @NickTurtle never tried myself but theoretically yes, it's called before image download, so the image can't appear without it's approval. [The docs](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/blob/master/docs/constructor.md) say that you need to "return false from this function to continue standard behavior" or "return true to intercept incoming request". So you have to check if user is allowed to access this image, if yes return false, else display whatever error message you want and return true.

Comment: I wonder how it would do that though. Will Dropbox (or Amazon S3) contact my server to determine whether or not to send the image to the client then?

Comment: @NickTurtle `interceptDownload` is called just after the download request, so it's called before contacting Dropbox/Amazon S3. Everything happens in your side, if `interceptDownload` return false it will start making the contact with the storage provider, and if you return true it will just stop there without even contacting Dropbox/Amazon S3.

Answer (score 2):

You usually have two things you can do when considering granting access to resources:

1. Authentication and access control
2. Indirect object references with sufficient entropy to make brute force attacks hopeless.

Point 1 is more or less obvious.
Point 2 is actually what you have already on your mind. To reason about the security of the second approach let's consider following:

- The entropy of `A3eedAcRCqCa32451`.jpg is about 80 bits.
- The count of the domain is 2^80 = 1208925819614629174706176.
- An attacker can try to guess the secret.
- Let's say, he can make 10 guesses a second and on average he will guess after |domain|/2 tries.
- It would take the attacker ~2 mln years to guess.

Now the domain of 80 bits is a bit small from the security perspective. Make it 128 bits by using type 4 UUIDs. I believe you see where this is going.

Comment: Another thing I was worrying about is if there was some way to list all the images in a bucket, but I saw another answer which described how to prevent it on Amazon S3.